# CSS: flex-grow maintain vertical aspect ratio

Tags: css

I am creating a website with a circular menu. The website content should fit all onto the homepage without the need to scroll. The menu needs to fill the remaining space on the homepage. However, I am unsure how to maintain the shape of the circle while filling the remaining space on the homepage using `flex-grow: 1`. Is there a way I can do this with pure CSS? Setting the menu to a set viewport size is not acceptable, it needs to fill the remaining space. I am not having luck using the traditional `padding-top: 100%` to maintain aspect ratio. The circle is not quite circular and it takes up twice the remaining space.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
}

#title {
  font-size: 30px;
}

#circle {
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

#footer {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="title">Title</div>
<div>navigation</div>
<div id="circle"></div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
</body>
```

**Edit**

I have figured out a way to maintain the aspect ratio of the circle filling the remaining space with flex grow. However, it is what I would consider a hack so I am leaving this question open.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
}

#title {
  font-size: 30px;
}

#circle {
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  /*width: max-content;*/
  padding: 0%;
  align-self: center;
}

#circle img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  justify-content: center;
}

#footer {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="title">Title</div>
<div>navigation</div>
<div id="circle"><img src="https://luxury.zappos.com/search/imgs/blank.20190219170746.png"></div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
</body>
```

**Edit 2**

It seems I was mislead by caniuse.com. This solution does not seem to work in most browsers besides chrome. Is there another solution?

Comment: honestly im not sure there is a way without setting explicit dimensions, since theres no way to determine how tall it is at any given point. if u knew the height of all the other elements, u could set an explicit `height`/`width` with `calc`

Comment: Unfortunately there is another menu, not included in this example that has text that will wrap depending on the screen width.

Comment: i dont believe `max-content` is widely supported? is it?

Comment: It looks like if I use the right keywords, every browser but IE. https://caniuse.com/#search=max-content `overflow: auto` also works but but has the disadvantage of cutting off my menu items.

Comment: Even stranger removing `width: max-content` and replacing it with `padding: 0%` achieves the same effect.

Comment: thats super quirky

Answer (score -1):

Put the circle div inside a wrapper div in your HTML:

```
<div id="circle-wrap">
  <div id="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Then move the `flex` rule to the wrapper:

```
#circle-wrap {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
}

#title {
  font-size: 30px;
}

#circle-wrap {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#circle {
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

#footer {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="title">Title</div>
<div>navigation</div>
<div id="circle-wrap">
  <div id="circle"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
</body>
```

Comment: doesnt work since `innerHeight` isnt always proportional to `innerWidth`. test it in a browser. additionally, the circle in the demo you posted always stays the same size. im assuming it should be responsive, hence no explicit dimensions